# Pagination in laravel 5 with realtion on where condition

Tags: laravel, pagination, relation

**Model** smsHeader

```
protected $fillable = [
    'type',
    'imei',
    'login',
    'ver'
];

public function detail()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Model\smsDetail', 'id_header');
}
```

**Controller**

```
$smsheader = smsHeader::orderBy('id', 'desc')->where('login', $user->email)->paginate(20);
    return view('app.inbox')->with('smsheader', $smsheader);
```

**Views**

```
  @foreach($smsheader as $header)
          @foreach($header->detail->where('type', '1') as $detail)
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{$detail->number}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$detail->name}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$detail->text}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$detail->date}}</td>
                                </tr>
          @endforeach
   @endforeach
```

but the result of pagination it was error, how i can set paginition in where smsdetail condition....??
sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 2):

The error is showing for this line `$header->detail->where('type', '1')`
you can access `$header->detail` within foreach if you want to use where condition then you need to use `get()` at the end,like below

```
@foreach($smsheader as $header)
      @foreach($header->detail->where('type', '1')->get() as $detail)
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{$detail->number}}</td>
                                <td>{{$detail->name}}</td>
                                <td>{{$detail->text}}</td>
                                <td>{{$detail->date}}</td>
                            </tr>
      @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: actually, i've already tried.. without get(); it's ok...

the error i mean is about pagination... the pagination show about $smsheader not in $detail where condition...

example...
in smsheader::where('login', $user->email) they have 100 results data (5 paginate)... but in view i set where again in detail()... and where in detail just show 20 data... it must show 2 paginate in my view not 5... thanks before..

Comment: @Megandi your where condition will not effect on $smsheader.If you need you have to do this on controller.

Comment: may you tell me how to do that??

Comment: You can use whereHas.For more https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations

Answer (score 0):

Laravel Queries within Blade views do not automatically execute. They simply prepare another QueryBuilder instance. You still need to run one of the "execute" methods (that will run PDOStatement::execute() underneath). These methods are:

- first() (returns first result from result set as single object)
- get() (which returns a Collection (ArrayObject with some added extra functionality))
- paginate($numberPerPage) (which returns a Collection with extra meta information to pass to a $links property accessible via $collection->links())

In your example:

```
@foreach($smsheader as $header)
      @foreach($header->detail->where('type', '1')->get() as $detail)
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{$detail->number}}</td>
                                <td>{{$detail->name}}</td>
                                <td>{{$detail->text}}</td>
                                <td>{{$detail->date}}</td>
                            </tr>
      @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: actually, i've already tried.. without get(); it's ok... the error i mean is about pagination... the pagination show about $smsheader not in $detail where condition... example... in smsheader::where('login', $user->email) they have 100 results data (5 paginate)... but in view i set where again in detail()... and where in detail just show 20 data... it must show 2 paginate in my view not 5... thanks before.. and sorry for my bad english